# Dropdown Select value and send it to another page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Hello i'm using a small form but unfortunately it not works

Here's my code

```
<script language="javascript">
     function goPage() {
          if (document.frm.language.value != '') {   
              document.frm.action = document.frm.language.value;
              document.frm.submit();   
          }
     }
</script>

<form name="frm" method="get">  
     <select name="language">
        <option value="">select one</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page1/">Page1</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page2/">Page2</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page3/">Page3</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page4/">Page4</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page5/">Page5</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page6/">Page6</option>
     </select>
     <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:goPage()" />
</form>
```

In this form, it only sends to http://example.com/ but i want to redirect it to particular page , please help

Comment: Why don't you change `http://example.com/` by what you want then?

Comment: where you write  http://example.com/ in your code? may be your go to right page then that page will redirect to  http://example.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please change name attribute to id like

`<select id="language">` I think it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in this code. It is working fine. Run the code snippet, I added an alert box which is showing the exact URL of the page which is selected from the form.

```js
     function goPage() {
          if (document.frm.language.value != '') {   
              document.frm.action = document.frm.language.value;
              alert( document.frm.language.value);
              document.frm.submit();   
          }
     }
```

```html
<form name="frm" method="get">  
     <select name="language">
        <option value="">select one</option>
        <option value="http://google.com">Page1</option>
        <option value="http://yahoo.com">Page2</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page3/">Page3</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page4/">Page4</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page5/">Page5</option>
        <option value="http://example.com/page6/">Page6</option>
     </select>
     <input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:goPage()" />
</form>
```